Rate of work of traction on a growing surface
Consider a deformable body, $\mathbb{A}(t)$, subjected to time-dependent surface traction $\mathbf{t}(t)$. When the mass of a body is constant, the rate of mechanical work by $\mathbf{t}(t)$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dW}{dt}=\int_{\mathbb{A}(t)} \mathbf{t}\cdot \mathbf{v} \ dA
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{v}$ represents the velocity field. However, this expression becomes invalid for a growing body with mass being added to its surface. To understand why, consider a bar subjected to an axial traction, where its length is increasing on one side due to mass addition. Even for a rigid bar, the work rate of the traction would be non-zero, as the bar’s center of mass shifts with the added mass, meaning that the total axial force contributes to the work. The rate of this work would equal the total axial force multiplied by the velocity of the bar’s center of mass.
Now, my question is:
Consider surface $\mathbb{A}(t)$ subjected to a traction field $\mathbf{t}(t)$ where boundary points on $\partial\mathbb{A}(t)$ move with a known velocity field due to growth. What is the correct expression for the rate of work of $\mathbf{t}(t)?
Update: I have added a diagram for the 1d version of the problem with a constant traction. The dashed part represents the mass added by the growth. Descriptions in the comments.

I don’t understand what the problem is. The equation you originally presented gives the amount of work being done for unit time on the on the material within the boundary.

Yes, but what if mass is continuously added at the boundary, causing the boundary to grow? Is this equation still valid? Clearly not. As I mentioned above, let’s simplify by considering a 1D rigid body with no internal velocity field. The body is subjected to a constant traction t.

The left end is fixed, while the right end grows with velocity
v due to the addition of mass. As mass is added, the 'new region' of the body also experiences the constant traction t. Although the velocity field within the body is zero (and thus, the integral above vanishes), the work done by the constant traction is non-zero because the center of mass shifts to the right. Therefore, I believe a boundary term must be added to the integral to account for the work required for the boundary growth.

How is the mass added and where is the traction applied?  Diagram?

You can think of it like the growth of a stalagmite or biological growth. We can assume there is a surrounding reservoir of "particles" that can attach and become part of the body. Traction by definition is a distributed surface vector (force/area^2 or in the 1D case force/length).

What causes the traction?

To make it even easier, let's consider the growth of a hanging stalactite. Let us assume it is a 1D body, the upper end is fixed and mass is only added to the bottom point. The question: Is the work of weight non-zero?

I've included a sketch for the 1D version of the problem with a constant traction. The source of the traction is irrelevant. For the growth of a hanging stalactite, you can assume it's the weight per unit length (though technically, weight is a body force).

If the body is elastic, the internal velocities are not zero,  but in your example, the velocity at the top is zero. And at the bottom, the traction is essentially zero,  so no work is being done.

The traction at the bottom cannot be zero because it is externally applied. The work, however, could be zero but I find it difficult to grasp how. As the body grows and the center of mass shifts downward, the resultant force from traction, multiplied by the displacement of the center of mass, should result in non-zero work.

Do you know how to solve this using Newton's 2nd law?
